# Please execute 'magento-cli' instead of 'magento' that uses the proper user to execute any Magento's command

Tags: magento2, magento-2.2.5, amazon

Anyone can help me this problem ?

```
Please execute 'magento-cli' instead of 'magento' that uses the proper user to execute any Magento's command
```

This problem happen when i run command : `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple, just using 'magento-cli' instead of 'magento'

Example :

```
sudo bin/magento-cli setup:upgrade
sudo bin/magento-cli setup:static-content:deploy -f
sudo bin/magento-cli indexer:reindex
sudo bin/magento-cli cache:flush
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Login to your account using ssh

2. At the command prompt, change to the directory where Magento is installed. For example, if Magento is installed in the document root directory, type cd ~/public_html.

3. Type the following command to make the CLI executable

```
chmod 744 bin/magento
```

4. To run the CLI and view the available command options, type the following command

```
bin/magento
```

Comment: Thanks you, it works, or run command : sudo bin/magento-cli instead of sudo bin/magento